# ReactJS: dropdown list in table row

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to create table, in which one row contains "selected options", as showed below:
[image]

By clicking on dropdown list, user gets an opportunity to select between 2 options: Expenditure and Revenue. After select, the selected option render in cell, and data selected value stored in component state (to be able to be send to server-side, for example).

Futher my code:

First parent component:

```
class Table extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        data: [
            {'Date': '', 'Operation': '', 'Amount': '', 'Item_of_expenditure': '', 'Balance': ''}
        ]
    };
    this.getHeader = this.getHeader.bind(this);
    this.getRowsData = this.getRowsData.bind(this);
    this.getKeys = this.getKeys.bind(this);
    this.addRow = this.addRow.bind(this);
    this.setOperation = this.setOperation.bind(this);
}

getKeys = function () {
    return Object.keys(this.state.data[0]);
};

getHeader = function () {
    var keys = this.getKeys();
    return keys.map((key) => {
        return <th key={key}>{key.toLowerCase()}</th>
    })
};

getRowsData = () => {
    var items = this.state.data;
    var keys = this.getKeys();
    return items.map((row, index) => {
        return <tr key={index}><RenderRow key={index} data={row} keys={keys} onSelectedOperation={this.setOperation(index, option)}/></tr>
    })
};

setOperation = (index, option) => {
    let existRow = this.state.data[index];
    let operation = existRow.Operation;
    operation.set(option);
    existRow.set(operation);
    this.setState({data: existRow});
};

addRow = function () {
    let existRows = this.state.data;
    existRows.push({'Date': '', 'Operation': '', 'Amount': '', 'Item_of_expenditure': '', 'Balance': ''});
    this.setState({data: existRows});
};

render() {
    return (
        <div className={styles}>
            <table>
                <thead>
                <tr>{this.getHeader()}</tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                {this.getRowsData()}
                </tbody>
                <button onClick={this.addRow}>
                    Add new row
                </button>
            </table>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Table/>,
    document.getElementById("app")
);
```

Second component, which used in "getRowsData" for rendering each row:

```
class RenderRow extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleOperation = this.handleOperation.bind(this);
}

handleOperation = (selectedOperation) => {
    this.props.onSelectedOperation(selectedOperation);
};

render() {
    return this.props.keys.map((key) => {
        var rowValue;
        if (key === 'Operation') {
            rowValue = <OperationSelect onSelectOperation={this.handleOperation}/>
        } else {
            rowValue = this.props.data[key]
        }
        return <td key={this.props.data[key]}>{rowValue}</td>
    })
   }
 }
```

Third component (for dropdown list):

```
class OperationSelect extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: 'expenditure'};
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}

handleChange =(event) => {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
    this.props.onSelectOperation(event.target.value);
};

render() {
    return (
        <label>
            <select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
                <option value="expenditure">Expenditure</option>
                <option value="revenue">Revenue</option>
            </select>
        </label>
    );
  }
}
```

Expected behavior, one more time: when user clicks on the option in dropdown list, the selected value:

- render in table cell (by defauld - "Expenditure");
- saved in state.data.Operation of Table-component. So, the default value is: "data: [{'Date': '', 'Operation': '', 'Amount': '', 'Item_of_expenditure': '', 'Balance': ''}]".  Expected value afrer change is - "data: [{'Date': '', 'Operation': 'Revenue', 'Amount': '', 'Item_of_expenditure': '', 'Balance': ''}]"

For this aim I tried to send the selected value from child component "OperationSelect" to parent - "Table".
But I faced with 2 problems, when I select the option in dpordown list:
[image]

Then - IDEA underline with a wavy line props "onSelectedOperation" and "onSelectOperation" in:

```
handleOperation = (selectedOperation) => {
    this.props.onSelectedOperation(selectedOperation);
};
```

and:

```
handleChange =(event) => {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
    this.props.onSelectOperation(event.target.value);
};
```

IDEA recognize this props as... a function.